# Compute instances got deleted after hours of 100% CPU usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We noticed that multiple compute instances got deleted at the same time after hours of 100% CPU usage. Because of this deletion, the hours of computation was lost.

Can anyone tell us why they got deleted?

I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/tkngch/a8067a97c36b653cc22e10ae44f3ef80) with the only log we could find in Stackdriver logging around the time of deletion.

Comment: Looks like someone or a script ran gcloud compute instances delete from one of the instances in you project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The log files show the following pieces of information:**

- The deleter's source IP address `34.89.101.139`. Check if this matches the public IP address of the instance that was deleted. This IP address is within Google Cloud.
- The User-Agent specifies that the Google Cloud SDK CLI `gcloud` is the program that deleted the instance.
- The Compute Engine Default Service Account provided the permissions to delete the instance.

In summary, a person or script ran the CLI and deleted the instance using your project's Compute Engine Default Service Account key from a Google Cloud Compute service.

**Future Suggestions:**

1. Remove the permission to delete instances from the Compute Engine Default Service Account or (better) create a new service account that only has the required permissions for this instance.
2. Do not share service accounts in different Compute Engine instances.
3. Create separate SSH keys for each user that can SSH into the instance.
4. Enable Stackdriver logging of the SSH Server `auth.log` file. You will then know who logged into the instance.